# How to know external ip adress of the current pc

Tags: c#, .net

For example to get local ip address I use:

```
 string myHost = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
 string myIP = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(myHost).AddressList[0].ToString();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's a link that may help.  http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/24692-showing-the-external-ip-address-in-c%23/

There's a good post on doing a webrequest to WhatIsMyIP.com

Comment: +1 - a web request is the ONLY way to do it. You need to get into the internet to know whether you are behind 1 or more NAT devices. SO, a web based API call to some external server returning your IP is it.